# What are the 'Client Profile' versions of .net framework 3.5 and 4 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I don't know the differences between 3.5 and 3.5 `Client Profile`, same for 4.

So, what's up with that?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx):

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications.

It is useful when you need to redistribute the framework with your application (for example click-once):

> Applications that target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile typically improve the deployment experience by having smaller download sizes and quicker install times. An application that targets the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile has a smaller redistribution package that installs the minimum set of client assemblies on the user's computer, without requiring the full version of the .NET Framework 4 to be present.