# What is the difference between .NET version 3.5 and .NET version 3.5 client profile

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I am writing a **windows service** and want to support old Windows -7 platform by choosing 3.5. Which one should I go for ? [image]

Comment: The recommendation from Microsoft was to always target the Client Profile unless you need something that is not in the Client Profile. The Client Profile is a subset of the full framework for hopefully a smaller footprint.

Comment: Not exact dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949360/what-are-the-client-profile-versions-of-net-framework-3-5-and-4-in-visual-stu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Client profile is a subset of the full framework. The rational is that not every application needs everything the framework has to offer, so you are allowed to use the client profile to minimize the requirements of your application.

From the [.NET Framework Client Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/cc656912(v=vs.90)) page for 3.5 version:

> The .NET Framework Client Profile is a subset of the full .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 that targets client applications. It provides a streamlined subset of Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), and ClickOnce features. This enables rapid deployment scenarios for WPF, Windows Forms, WCF, and console applications that target the .NET Framework Client Profile.

And a bit further down:

> Target the .NET Framework Client Profile when you need the fastest possible deployment experience for your WPF or Windows Forms client application. A .NET Framework Client Profile application has a redistribution package that installs the minimum set of client assemblies on the target computer, without requiring the full .NET Framework to be present.

Please note that the [client profile was discontinued in .NET Framework 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/client-profile), 
and only the full framework is available in later versions.

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available. Optimizations provided by the .NET Framework 4.5, such as smaller download size and faster deployment, have eliminated the need for a separate deployment package. The single redistributable streamlines the installation process and simplifies your app's deployment options.